# Scale parameter for Numpy arcsinh np.arcsinh() tranformation function

Tags: python, numpy, transformation

I am trying to apply an arcsinh transformation to certain columns of a data frame using numpy.arcsinh(). Here is my line of code:

data_frame[column_list] = np.arcsinh(data_frame[column_list])

It appears to work great, and seems to be doing what I want it to do.

There's only one problem: there is no option to change the scale parameter of the arcsinh transformation.

The standard we use for cytometry data (which is what I work on) is 5. That's the point on the x-axis where the graph goes from being linear to log scaled, if you plot the data.

I have used this in R, the 'asinh' function, but there is an option to specify the scale parameter, which I believe the default is 5.

For this numpy arcsinh method, I can find no information on how to change the scale parameter, or even what the default is. I have read the documentation on this page: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arcsinh.html and I have been googling for several hours, but I cannot find the answer to this.

Any help would be much appreciated, even if it's just how to go about finding the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what this scale parameter is supposed to be. If it is an X value after which you want the behavior of the function to change, you need to use splices and np where to apply 2 different functions to the portions of the array. If it is just a multiplicative constant than just multiply by it.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's `numpy.arcsinh` is not a specialized display scaling function. It's the hyperbolic arc-sine. The hyperbolic arc-sine doesn't have a scale parameter. (The same seems to be true for R's `asinh`; I don't see a scale parameter in the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Hyperbolic.html).)

From the [google results](https://support.cytobank.org/hc/en-us/articles/206148057-About-the-Arcsinh-transform) for arcsinh transforms in cytometry data display, it looks like the computation you want is

```
numpy.arcsinh(data_frame[column_list] / scale)
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out today. Thank you so much for putting in all this effort to help me.